# HandlerExceptionResolver for annotated controller

Tags: spring, exception, controller

I have annotated controller which contains several methinds mapped on urls. Like this:

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/addCategories")
public void addCategories(@RequestParam(value = "data") String jsonData) throws ParseException

@RequestMapping(value = "/getNext")
public void getNext(@RequestParam(value = "data") String jsonData) throws ParseException

...

}
```

Methods need to parse json request and do perform some actions. Parsing request may produce checked `ParseException` which I can handle in method or add `throws` to its signature. I prefer second approach since in this I don't want additional try/catch in code.
So the question is how to configure and code handler for controller methods?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out spring documentation for [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler).

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {

@ExceptionHandler(ParseException.class)
public ModelAndView handleParseExc(ParseException ex) {
  //...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addCategories")
public void addCategories(@RequestParam(value = "data") String jsonData) throws ParseException


}
```

Or subclass [`AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.html) and declare it as a spring mvc bean in your xml configuration if you want to handle these exceptions for all your controllers.

Comment: Or subclass AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver and annotate it with @Component if you want to skip the xml configuration.